# What is the IP range(s) of Google pub/sub?

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Google pub/sub subscription that pushes messages for a topic to an AppEngine standard service endpoint.

I want to restrict access to the AppEngine standard service to user IPs and still allow for messages coming from Google Pub/sub.

In the AppEngine firewall, the only option is to allow certain IP ranges.

What is the IP range(s) of Google pub/sub?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-pubsub-discuss/OWn5HWpwFbo/iikxnF0-AgAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that all the IP requests from Pub/Sub push subscriptions are coming from `2002:axx:xxxx::`. As per IETF [RFC 3056](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3056), `2002:::` is an `6to4` range. `2002:axx:xxxx::`, then, is translated to `10.XXX.XXX.XXX`, which is an range reserved for the internal networking in this case used by Google.

**Note**: that other services apart from Pub/Sub might [at some point] use range `2002:a00::/24`, `10.XXX.XXX.XXX`. For example [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services). If requests from Flexible are not describable in this particular project then you will have block it and give it a higher priority.

In the end your Firewall entries:

```
10      Allow   2002:a00::/24   Pub/Sub 
default Deny    *               The default action.
```

Also, there is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111425485) created about it in Google's issue-tracker.