# What is the ip-ranges for of Cloud Pub/Sub and Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to make infrastructure for dening from unknown users.

Following is the imaging architecture.
Cloud Scheduler and Cloud PubSub -> GLB -> GCE

If these ip-ranges update, I would like to know about updating. Could I have how to know updating?
In addition, if you know ip-ranges by using GCP, please let me know.

I know similar to [What is the IP range(s) of Google pub/sub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172165/what-is-the-ip-ranges-of-google-pub-sub) but this article didn't write down how to know ip-ranges.

Comment: You should control access using service accounts / IAM, not by IP address. If you try to do it by IP, then all someone has to do is set up a machine inside GCP and access your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question but for Google SMTP and Google Cloud Shell you get google IP Ranges through their cloud-shell through SPF records as shown below. The ranges are quite broad so I think it applies all google cloud public IPs.

To verify find one IP and see if falls within any of the rages specified if so then it's most likely to be correct

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks2.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks3.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

See this thread for more info: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764

Here's the cloud shell thread where they mention how to get public ip ranges:

> For the feature to work, you must allow connections either from any IP address or **from Google's IP address range, which you can retrieve by using public SPF records.**