# How to whitelist GCP cloud scheduler ip in aws EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, amazon-vpc, google-cloud-scheduler

I am running a server on **AWS EC2**, which runs only for some **whitelisted ips**. I want to use **GCP cloud scheduler** for running my cron jobs. So I want to whitelist GCP cloud scheduler request in EC2 server.

I tried google and cloud scheduler documentation, but nothing found regarding ip whitelisting.

Please let me know any way I can achieve this.

Comment: You can't authorize a DNS with AWS firewall?

Answer (score 1):

In your security group for the instance, allow only the IPs from your GCP service. This will prevent any other IPs from accessing the service.

Comment: how to allow gcp server in security group. what are the ips of gcp server?

Comment: You need to determine that by checking the ips of your GCP service. Usually you would set a fixed public IP for the service and use that. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: thanks for the above link. I tried your solution but it didn't worked may be I am doing something wrong. I am using cloud scheduler service, how can i attach static ip for cloud scheduler. I also tried **External IP addresses** but no option to attach with scheduler.

Comment: Here is discussion regarding the IP ranges for gcp services. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264860/what-is-the-ip-ranges-for-of-cloud-pub-sub-and-cloud-scheduler